# My if statement with char comparison isn't working, any ideas?

Tags: c++, if-statement, string-comparison

Here is my code

```
char un [50] = "Username";
char pw [50]=  "Password";
char unapp[50];
char pwapp[50];

cout << "Username: ";
cin >> unapp;
system("CLS");
cout << "Username: ";
cout <<  unapp <<endl;
cout << "Password: ";
cin >> pwapp;
system ("pause");

if (unapp == un)
{
          cout <<"Gz" <<endl;
          system ("pause");
          }

cout << unapp <<endl;
cout << un <<endl;

system ("pause");

return 0;
```

For some reason it does not run the `if` statement even though after that I have printed both the `unapp` and `un` to see if they are the same and sure enough they are but still nothing?? However, it works if I use `int`s.

Comment: Or, better yet, use `std::string`.

Comment: You are using C-strings. The `==` operator doesn't do anything special with C-strings, just as you cannot use it to compare a raw array of integers.  Use `strncmp`.

Answer (score 2):

To compare your two `char*`, you should use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

```
if (strcmp (unapp ,un) != 0) {}
```

Another alternative is to use `std::string`

Comment: Could you give me a example on how to use this using my code?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

Since arrays decay into pointers, what you are doing is comparing pointers, not the contents of the arrays.

What you are actually trying to do is comparing the buffers (or strings) these pointers are pointing to. In order to do so just use `strcmp` as Jerome L explained, or just implement a loop that iterates over all the elements of the arrays and compares then till a '\0' terminator is found.